# Socket Behaviour - Data written out of order

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, networking

I have an interface where threads write into a socket and are received by a remote server.  When the thread contention becomes high, there is an issue where the socket data is out of order.  I have a "standard" message that is being sent through the socket and I can see at the byte level that a second logical message is being written half way through the first logical message.  obviously this means that the interface fails as the data is corrupted.

The only special setting that is used on the socket is

```
m_socket.SetSocketOption(System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel.Tcp,
System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName.NoDelay, 1)
m_Socket.Connect(m_remoteServerName, m_remoteServerPort)
```

I tried the simple solution of putting a lock around my logical message, so my logic was:

```
lock (sending)
{
    msgbytes = GetLogicalMessage();
    m_socket.Send(msgbytes, 0, msgbytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

The receiver is effectively doing the opposite, reading a message header followed by a message payload from each of the logical messages.

The send method is being accessed from multiple threads, but I'm stumped as where to look.  I've looked through the code and all access to the socket is via the locked method (except for receiving).  I can't see anything obvious other than if .Send() doesn't work the way I expect it to.  It is a stream from my understanding, so the buffer write will need to complete, even if the data isn't pushed out the socket on conclusion of the call.

Comment: Just as with `Receive()`, you must check the return value of `Send()`. Not all bytes have to be written to the send buffer (at least in non-blocking mode).

Comment: also we cant see GetLogicalMEssage. I hope you are not expecting to get messages in that correspond to sends. They can be chopped up into pieces - but will always arrive in order (or not at all)

Comment: I serialize logical messages into the stream.  at the other end I read logical messages back out and deserialize them.  I understand the transport can get them there in strange ways, but the stream is guaranteed to be in order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your understanding of the `Send` method is incorrect - it does not guarantee that all bytes you give it are placed into the socket send buffer. The buffer might not have enough space, so you have to pay attention to the return value, which is the number of bytes that got copied.

#### Edit 0:

Usual technique is to loop around `send`. Mind the fact that in-kernel TCP/IP stack drains the buffer asynchronously, so it's not necessarily true that the next call to `send` will block again.

Still this is not too pretty in the presence of threads since you'll get arbitrary delays on sending messages.

I would probably suggest moving socket handling into its own thread, and connecting workers to it via a queue, which would accommodate spikes in your messaging.

Comment: What is the appropriate behaviour if the bytes aren't fully written?  Advance the pointer on the buffer and call send again?  I assume if the buffer is full when I make the call, it woudl still be full if I tried again

Comment: @Spence If the buffer is full you can end up spinning for a while waiting for space to write the next block of data to.  Much better to have a single thread handling the communications with others posting information to it via a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265).  Then they can get on with what they are doing without waiting for the send to complete.